# iOS swift How to call Alamofire with call back to get the data in Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, alamofire

I am using Alamofire [pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.3'] in my project and AFWrapper created in wrapper class for Alamofire functions how to use completion handlers to get the data in view controllers.

```
this is AFWrapper class code
     class AFWrapper
            {
  This is my post request code

        func requestPOSTURL(_ strURL : String, params : [String : AnyObject]?, headers : [String : String]?, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){
            Alamofire.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
                //print(responseObject)
                if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                    let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
                    success(resJson)
                }
                if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                    let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
                    let dic = ["NSLocalizedDescription" : error.localizedDescription]
                    failure(error)
                }
            }
        }

This is my get request code

                func requestGetWithParamsURL(_ strURL : String, headers : [String : String]?, params : [String : AnyObject]?, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){

                    Alamofire.request(strURL, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
                        //print(responseObject)
                        if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                            let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
                            success(resJson)
                        }
                        if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                            let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
                            let dic = ["NSLocalizedDescription" : error.localizedDescription]


                            failure(error)
                        }
                    }

                }


        }
```

Comment: you will have a lot of problems with this structure. Best remove callbacks and use delegation pattern and clear separation between UI / network operations.

Comment: @KirilS.   can you suggest best pattern to get Alamofire data in VC. can you provide some Demo code.

Comment: many examples available if you look for "alamofire demo mvvm". Here's a good example: https://medium.com/@arifinfrds/mvvm-on-ios-with-alamofire-f3cd273e6092